# How do I write one query to get data from multiple tables containing similar name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Starting with, I can't change the naming conventions for the tables. However I want to run the same query against each table WITHOUT having to go in and change the table name each time. The tables I have are as follows:

```
Customer
------------
CLOG201902
CLOG201901
CLOG201812.....(one per month going back 10 years. The average CLOG table contains 200,000 lines.
```

From the customer record I will pull the `CustomerName`, `Account`, `Address`.

From EACH CLOG table I will pull date, time, `EventType`, etc.

Filtering by: `Customer.instno = 38` (only need to pull for that installer #) and only relevant alarm activity (fire, burg, etc)

I have tried (reason why it didn't work at the bottom of the code):

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CUSTID
    , KEYALM
    , CUSTPRIV.NAME AS "PROPERTY NAME"
    , EVENTNAME AS "ALARM TYPE"
    , EVSTRING
    , ZONE
    , POINTID
    , USRNO
    , CUSTOMER.BRANCHNO
FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + '  INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + ' .SERIALNO INNER JOIN
    CUSTPRIV ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = CUSTPRIV.SERIALNO
WHERE KEYALM IS NOT NULL
    AND BRANCHNO = 38
    AND EVENTNAME IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL '
FROM sys.tables where name like 'clog2019%'

SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)

SELECT @sql 
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

(This DOES produce everything, however I cannot filter down more, to not include the EVENTNAME OF "OPEN", "CLOSE", "TEST". They only want to see the actual alarm lines)

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = STUFF
((
     SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT  FROM ' + NAME AS [text()]
     FROM sys.tables
     WHERE NAME LIKE 'CLOG2019%' 
     FOR XML PATH('')
) ,1,11,'');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

This also returns every line and I can't seem to filter with a where clause at all.

If I was going to run each months query separately, it would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EVDATE,(1)) AS DATE
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR,EVDATE,(8)) AS TIME
    , CUSTID
    , KEYALM
    , EVENTNAME
    , EVSTRING
    , ZONE
    , POINTID
    , USRNO
    , CUSTOMER.BRANCHNO
FROM CLOG201902  INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = CLOG201902.SERIALNO INNER JOIN
    CUSTPRIV ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = CUSTPRIV.SERIALNO
WHERE KEYALM IS NOT NULL
    AND BRANCHNO = 38
    AND (EVENTNAME LIKE 'CRITICAL'
        OR EVENTNAME LIKE 'FIRE'
        OR EVENTNAME LIKE 'BURGLARY')
```

(the bummer part of this is I have to change the CLOG for every month (120 times)

Thanks for any help! I am learning by trial and error...... no formal training.

**SOLUTION** THANKS BRIAN!
    DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max) = ''

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CUSTID
    , KEYALM
    , CUSTPRIV.NAME AS "PROPERTY NAME"
    , EVENTNAME AS "ALARM TYPE"
    , EVSTRING
    , ZONE
    , POINTID
    , USRNO
    , CUSTOMER.BRANCHNO
FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + '  INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + ' .SERIALNO INNER JOIN
    CUSTPRIV ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = CUSTPRIV.SERIALNO
WHERE KEYALM IS NOT NULL
    AND BRANCHNO = 38
    AND EVENTNAME IS NOT NULL
    AND EVENTNAME NOT IN (''OPEN'', ''CLOSE'', ''TEST'') --double single quotes made the error go away and worked! 20,000 rows down to 1,061!

UNION ALL '
FROM sys.tables where name like 'clog2019%'


SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)

SELECT @sql 


exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but check out [sp_msforeachtable](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/)

Comment: Is this something you're going to do once, or many times in the future?   Why isn't the solution to take your first attempt and add `AND EVENTNAME NOT IN ('OPEN', 'CLOSE', 'TEST')` in the WHERE clause in the dynamic string?

Comment: When I add that line in the where clause I get an error saying "incorrect syntax near ', '

Comment: Please update your question to show, *exactly*, how you added it.  Remember that getting a single quote into a string is tricky - in the dynamic SQL string it would look like `'EventName Not In (''Open'', ''Close'', ''Test'')'` (I think)

Comment: YAY! Brian!! That worked! I learned something new again! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Brian. Thank you Brian! Solution - I was not formatting my EVENTNAME NOT IN list properly

```
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CUSTID
    , KEYALM
    , CUSTPRIV.NAME AS "PROPERTY NAME"
    , EVENTNAME AS "ALARM TYPE"
    , EVSTRING
    , ZONE
    , POINTID
    , USRNO
    , CUSTOMER.BRANCHNO
FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + '  INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].' + name + ' .SERIALNO INNER JOIN
    CUSTPRIV ON CUSTOMER.SERIALNO = CUSTPRIV.SERIALNO
WHERE KEYALM IS NOT NULL
    AND BRANCHNO = 38
    AND EVENTNAME IS NOT NULL
    AND EVENTNAME NOT IN (''OPEN'', ''CLOSE'', ''TEST'') --double single quotes made the error go away and worked! 20,000 rows down to 1,061!

UNION ALL '
FROM sys.tables where name like 'clog2019%'


SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)

SELECT @sql 


exec sp_executesql @SQL
```